# WPF Documentviewerbase.Print. Remove dialog box

Tags: wpf, documentviewer, printdialog

I am using WPF and the DocumentViewer to display a document. However, when I use DocumentViewerBase.Print, it gives the "standard" Windows dialog box asking me to choose a printer with the default already selected. How can I get rid of this? I just want to use a Print method that will automatically start printing with no other prompt in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in order to do this you would need to write your own printing routine e.g. by overriding *OnPrintCommand* method of the *DocumentViewer*. The reason is that default implementation is using *PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter* method to create *XpsDocumentWriter* object and shows a *PrintDialog* in order to define its properties. For more details check the *DocumentViewerBase.OnPrintCommand* with [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)